# Can't iterate through HttpHeaders Map

Tags: java, loops

My IDE says

> Error: can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

On the `headers.map()` in this code

```
import java.net.http.HttpHeaders;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;

public static String dumpRequest(HttpRequest request)
{
    HttpHeaders headers = request.headers();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : headers.map()) {

    }
}
```

However the documentation of the `map()` in my IDE says it returns a `Map<String, List<String>>` , what am I missing ? please consider I'm very new to JAVA

I'm using JAVA 14

This is the documentation of [HttpHeaders](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpHeaders.html) that I'm using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : headers.map().entrySet())
```

Map itself does not extend the `Iterable` interface, so it can't be iterated using foreach.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of spring's `HttpHeaders`: Simply do `headers.forEach((key, value) -> {...})`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one
for java http

```
public static String dumpRequest(HttpRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.headers()
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : headers.map().entrySet()) {

    }
}
```

for spring framework of java in case

```
public static String dumpRequest(HttpRequest request) {
    HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders()
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : headers.entrySet()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't have `getHeaders()` in my request object , am I using the right classes?

Comment: ummm, I don't think so, is it a framework for JAVA ? I will search on it

Comment: Please add full package-name/imports (for each sample) to avoid ambiguity.